# generic handler not fired in ImageUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net, handler

I created a program that should call a handler by imageUrl attribute from asp:image.
The problem is that if I try do this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imagemCapa" runat="server" CssClass="inserirImg2" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageHandler.ashx?cod=" + txtCod.Text %>'/>
```

My handler isn't fired.
I try to put the link directly, like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="imagemCapa" runat="server" CssClass="inserirImg2" ImageUrl='ImageHandler.ashx?cod=0'/>
```

And work normally, but I need use the first way. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you please prove a snippet of the rendered output from the browser?

Comment: Where is `txtCod` coming from? You haven't included a complete example. Please review [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your handler code looks like but have you tried

```
ImageUrl='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/ImageHandler.ashx?cod=" + txtCod.Text) %>'
```